# How to determine if an edge-triggered flip-flop is positive going or negative going?

Tags: flipflop

[image]

I have an SR flip-flop such as above, and I'm to determine whether it's positive-going or negative-going. How can I do that? 
I understand that edge-triggered flip-flops' output only change upon edges of clock. But I don't know how to determine which one.

Comment: This arrangement is usually called a master-slave flip-flop. It's not really edge-triggered although the output doesn't change until the clock goes low.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the slave flip flop in your schematic, IC2.  When will its outputs, Q and -Q change, relative to the clock?

Answer (score 0):

The IC1 Gates inputs when CP="1"  then IC2 gates those outputs when CP="0" to produce the change in output. When CP="0" IC1 is disabled so input changes cannot affect the output.

Thus you have a **positive CP enable state internal latch** going into a **negative edge CP output register.**